# NAudio select Speaker/Headphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)

Tags: c#, naudio, wasapi

Is it possible to select Speaker/Headphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)

```
var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
    foreach (var wasapi in enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.All, DeviceState.All))
           {
                {wasapi.DeviceFriendlyName} {wasapi.State}
              MessageBox.Show($" {wasapi.FriendlyName}");
               if (wasapi.FriendlyName.Contains("speaker"))
               {
                   device = ????????????????
                }
          }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Answer

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
            var devices = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.All, DeviceState.Active);

            //comboBox1.Items.AddRange(devices.ToArray()); //required
            foreach (var dev in devices)
            {

                comboBox1.Items.Add(dev);
            }

            comboBox1.Text = "Speaker/Headphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)";  //reauired

        }
```